# how to rename files in different directories?

Tags: php

I am trying to rename the files contained in 2 or more directories. Maybe this question was asked before but I'm stuck on this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated

**main directory:**

- resources/country

**sub folder where files located:**

- resources/country/USA/ (fileshere)
- resources/country/Thailand/ (fileshere)
- resources/country/England/ (fileshere)

  ```
  $dir = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/country");
  if(!empty($dir) && is_array($dir)){
      foreach($dir as $d){
              $sub_dir = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/country/".$d);

              if(!empty($sub_dir)){
                  foreach($sub_dir as $s_dir){
                      if($s_dir != '..' && $s_dir != '.'){
                          $mynew_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/country/".utf8_decode($d)."/";
                          if ($handle = opendir($mynew_dir)) {
                              while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
                                  //$newName = str_replace("SKU#","",$fileName);
                                  if(is_file($fileName)){
                                      $newName = urlencode($fileName);
                                      if(rename($fileName, $newName)){
                                          print"<div>Rename Successful: Filename:".$fileName." Newname: ".$newName."</div>";
                                      }else{
                                          print"<div>Rename UnSuccessful: Filename:".$fileName." Newname: ".$newName."</div>";
                                      }

                                  }

                              }
                              closedir($handle);
                          }else{
                              print  print"<div>Rename UnSuccessful: Failed to open: " .$d."</div>";  
                          }

                      }
                  }
              }else{
                  print"<div>Rename UnSuccessful: Empty</div>";                   
              }
          }
      }
  ```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to tell us what specifically you are having trouble with; right now there isn’t a real question here to begin with.

Comment: I agree, the question may lack a little description. Anyway I managed to find the problem, however I mysels is currently stuck on solving it. =) The problem lies in directory traversial. Currently it is faulty, because at minimum `scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/country")` wil return an `array( 0 => '.' , 1 => '..')` even if `country`is completly empty. Which later in code causes directory to read itself for the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is_file() will treat '.' and '..' as files and will allow them in the path.
rename() needs absolute path

```
<?php
$dir = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/country");
if(!empty($dir) && is_array($dir))
 {

        foreach($dir as $d)
        {
            if(strcasecmp($d, '..')!=0 && strcasecmp($d, '.')!=0) //You need to check the first two files in the base directory as well. Else you will always go one directory back if the path contains '. or '..'
            {

                $sub_dir = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/country/".$d);

                if(!empty($sub_dir))
                {
                    foreach($sub_dir as $s_dir)
                    {

                        if(strcasecmp($s_dir, '..')!=0 && strcasecmp($s_dir, '.')!=0)
                        {
                            $mynew_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/country/".$d; // No need to use another '/'

                            if ($handle = opendir($mynew_dir)) 
                            {
                                while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) 
                                {
                                    //$newName = str_replace("SKU#","",$fileName);

                                    if(strcasecmp($fileName, '..')!=0 && strcasecmp($fileName, '.')!=0) //is_file treats '.' and '..' as files which you want to avoid 
                                    {
                                        $newName = urlencode($fileName);

                                        if(rename($mynew_dir."/".$fileName, $mynew_dir."/".$newName)) //rename() needs an absoulute path
                                        {
                                            print"<div>Rename Successful: Filename:".$fileName." Newname: ".$newName."</div>";
                                        }else{
                                            print"<div>Rename UnSuccessful: Filename:".$fileName." Newname: ".$newName."</div>";
                                        }

                                    }

                                }
                                closedir($handle);
                            }else{
                                print  print"<div>Rename UnSuccessful: Failed to open: " .$d."</div>";  
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    print"<div>Rename UnSuccessful: Empty</div>";                   
                }
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

I assume that the resource/ folder and this php script are in root directory. **If you want to place them inside another folder, add the folder name everywhere in $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/country/"**

Comment: I am afraid this solution is faulty as well. `strcasecmp($fileName, '..')!=0 && strcasecmp($fileName, '.')!=0` will also for directories inside `$mynew_dir`.

Comment: Also `is_file()` works perfectly fine when yu supply full path.

Answer (score 0):

Original code had a main problem - directory traversial. The base directory `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/country"` was read multiple times.

When the renaming itself occured, there were no checks if the `$fileName` is aclually a file - it was possible to rename directories as well.

Also there were several absolutely un-necessary error messages, which i removed.

The first answer was partly correct, `rename()` does need an absolute path.
However `is_file` works perfectly fine when you supply it an absolute path.

Assuming folder structure `/resourses/country/...` is placed in the servers document root folder(can be anything, not necessarly php root folder. Depends greatly on setups) the code for working exapmle will look like:

```
<?php

$dir = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/country");
if(!empty($dir) && is_array($dir)) {
    foreach($dir as $d) {
        /* $dir will always include '.' and '..' as the first two elemets of the array.
        *  The check below ensures, that you exclude these elements from further traversial. 
        *  If you don't make this check, you will also read the parent of your directory and the directory itself  
        */
        if($d != '.' && $d != '..') {
            /*
            *  Here, we ensure ourselves that we actually selected a directory and not a file.
            */
            if(is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/country/".utf8_decode($d)))
            {
                $sub_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/country/".utf8_decode($d)."/";
                /*
                *  Here, no extra checks are needed, we already ensured ourselves that we selected the correct directory.
                *  We just need to open it and read it's contents.
                */
                if ($handle = opendir($sub_dir)) {
                    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
                        /*
                        *  Here is_file() actually take care of all the necessary checks.
                        *  When absolute path is supplied, it will only return true for actual files.
                        *  '.' and '..' will be treated as non-files. Any subfolders will be also ignored.
                        */
                        if(is_file($sub_dir."/".$fileName))
                        {
                            /* Here we make file name modifications. It can be any modifications.
                            *  As an axample I added appending 'new_' to file name.
                            *  Also for the sake of not forgetiing we encode the new file name strate away;
                            */
                            $new_fileName = "new_" . $fileName;
                            $encoded_name = urlencode($new_fileName);
                            /*
                            *  Here we do  the renaming itself.
                            *  As it was said earlier 'rename()' needs an absolute path to work correctly 
                            */
                            if(rename($sub_dir."/".$fileName, $sub_dir."/".$new_fileName)) {
                                print"<div>Rename Successful: Filename: ".$fileName." Newname: ".$new_fileName."</div>";
                            } else {
                                print"<div>Rename UnSuccessful: Filename: ".$fileName." Newname: ".$new_fileName."</div>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    closedir($handle);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I left the comments inside the code, to explain a little better what the code does and why it does it.

The above example was tested on Windows, and works there. Linux can have problems with this, as far as I know folder must have attribute `x`(executable) set, for this code to work.

Comment: @Cristian Igay, Consider maring one of the answers as accepted to close this question. Please read: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Glad I could help